# Deploy meteor to bluemix with --settings?

Tags: json, meteor, ibm-cloud

I have a JSON file with initial admin user information in it. My startup.js uses that user data to create the first admin user on startup.

When I deploy to meteor, I use meteor deploy  --settings settings.json

How can I perform this similarly when deploying to bluemix so I can access my application with my user credentials?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Bluemix documentation](https://github.com/ind1go/bluemix-buildpack-meteor#notes):

> You can specify meteor settings by setting the METEOR_SETTINGS
>   environment variable:
>
> ```
> cf set-env [APP_NAME] METEOR_SETTINGS '{"herp":"derp"}'
> ```